# .mapToLong method logic

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I am using Java 8 .mapToLong and I cannot understand the logic behind it. I am getting 1156 values, but the length of b is of 34, so the program is doing 34 * 34=1156. I need to divide the total_population of each county by the number_of_cities in each county to get the average population of each county and push this population to the average_population list. Here is the code I am using

```
List<Long> average_population = total_population.stream()
.flatMapToLong(a -> number_of_cities.stream().mapToLong(b -> a / b))
.boxed()
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that `total_population` contains the population of each county, and `number_of_cities` contains the number of cities of each county, and the size of `total_population` is equal to the size of `number_of_cities`?

Comment: You really should start with a `County` object that contains the properties you need.

Comment: Yes, Janos each one has 34 instances. These are the number of cities  2
1
1
2
2
3
1
8
5
1
1
2
2
1
4
1
4
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
6
1
1
2
1
1
1
3 and these are the populations 213083
1469845
108821
190007
249661
415448
70543
2329730
723062
118968
681124
162295
148492
82287
2492701
60684
384602
173469
249042
132356
132950
181107
324074
153784
198645
103700
1460545
121721
100450
988942
67574
255473
104710
245658

Answer (score 2):

Your flatMap operation is dividing all city counts by all population counts instead of dividing counts on a per-county basis. The calculation is also backwards: you need to divide population by cities, not the other way around. Let's get rid of flatMap and use an `IntStream` instead so you can use a single index across the two lists:

```
IntStream.range(0, total_population.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> total_population.get(i) / number_of_cities.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

An even better approach would be to encapsulate your data into a single class so you don't have to keep multiple lists:

```
class County {
    private final int numberOfCities;
    private final int totalPopulation;

    public County(int numberOfCities, int totalPopulation) {
        this.numberOfCities = numberOfCities;
        this.totalPopulation = totalPopulation;
    }

    public int getNumberOfCities() {
        return numberOfCities;
    }

    public int getTotalPopulation() {
        return totalPopulation;
    }
}
```

Now, assuming we have a `List<County> counties`, we can collect the averages like this:

```
counties.stream()
        .map(county -> county.getTotalPopulation() / county.getNumberOfCities())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or we can add an average method to our class:

```
public getAverageCityPopulation() {
    return totalPopulation / numberOfCities;
}
```

And stream the averages like this:

```
counties.stream()
        .map(County::getAverageCityPopulation)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This worked great shmosel thank you for the explanation of flatMap.